# Efficient way to create new column based on nested if else conditions and comparing values from lists in R

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, lapply, tidyr

**Input** `dt` -

```
dt <- data.frame(a_check=c(1,2,1,1,2),
                 b_check=c(0,1,NA,1,15),
                 c_check=c(1,0,0,1,NA),
                 d_check=c(1,1,1,0,0),
                 e_check=c(1,NA,0,1,1))
```

**Validation Lists-**

```
valid_values <- list(a_check= c(1,2,3), b_check= c(0,1),c_check=c(0,1,2),d_check="possitive integer",e_check="positive integer")
required_list <- list(a_check= 1, b_check= 1,c_check=0,d_check=1,e_check=0)
col_type_list <- list(a_check= "factor", b_check= "factor",c_check="continuous",d_check="continuous",e_check="continuous")
```

**Question-**

I am trying to obtain below desired output, by using multiple `ifelse` conditions as below-

1. If `variable` is required in `required_list` and `dt` contains `NA` for that column than its should give `error` (variable cannot be NA because it is required).
2. If `variable` is `continuous` in `col_type_list` than it should contain only positive values in `dt` else (variable  must be a positive integer)
3. If `variable` is `factor` in `col_type_list` than its should match the value in `valid_value` list else (variable must be one of the following values).

I am able to obtain result using `nested for loops` but it is not efficient at all for large data set.

**My Code-**

```
param_names <- colnames(dt)

error_msg <- list()
error <- list()

for(i in 1:nrow(dt)){

  for(j in 1:length(param_names))
  { 
    if(get(param_names[j],required_list) %in% 1 & is.na(as.numeric(unlist(dt[param_names[j]]))[i]) == TRUE)
    {

      error_msg[j] <- paste0(toupper(param_names[j]), " cannot be NA because it is required")

    }

    ## continuous variable check
    else if(get(param_names[j],col_type_list)=="continuous"){

      if (is.na(as.numeric(unlist(dt[param_names[j]]))[i]) | as.numeric(unlist(dt[param_names[j]]))[i] < 0) {
        error_msg[j] <- paste0(toupper(param_names[j]), " must be a positive integer")
      } else {

        error_msg[j] <- NA
      }


    } else {
      ## factor variable check

      if(!(as.numeric(unlist(dt[param_names[j]]))[i] %in% get(param_names[j],valid_values))){
        error_msg[j] <- paste0(toupper(param_names[j]), " must be one of the following values ", paste(get(param_names[j],valid_values), collapse = '-'))

      } else {

        error_msg[j] <- NA

      }
    }

  } ## end of inner for loop

  error[i] <- paste(unlist(error_msg),collapse = " & ")

}## end of inner f

final_error <- unlist(error)
setDT(dt)
dt[,error := final_error]
dt[,error := gsub("NA & | NA \\s+ &", "\\1", error)]
dt[,error := gsub("& \\s+ NA | & NA", "\\1", error)]
```

**Output-**

```
> dt

    a_check b_check c_check d_check e_check                                                                                error
1:       1       0       1       1       1                                                                                   NA
2:       2       1       0       1      NA                                                   E_CHECK must be a positive integer
3:       1      NA       0       1       0                                                                 B_CHECK cannot be NA
4:       1       1       1       0       1                                                                                   NA
5:       2      15      NA       0       1 B_CHECK must be one of the following values 0-1 & C_CHECK must be a positive integer
```

**Note**- I know it can be achieved using something similar solution by @Jav

```
dt[, error := lapply(param_names, function(x) {
  ((get(x, dt) %in% get(x, valid_values))) %>%
    ifelse(., " ", paste(x, "should have valid values like -", paste(get(x, valid_values), collapse = " ")))
}) %>% Reduce(paste, .)]
```

But, I am struggling to use multiple `ifelse` condition using above solution.
I am looking for efficient and clean solution to avoid `for loops`.
Any other method would also work.

Comment: Fyi, there are many packages for applying input-validation rules, like vetr (which I use) and the alternatives listed at the bottom of its tutorial: https://github.com/brodieG/vetr

Comment: @Frank I usually prefer to create custom functions for error checking, but `vetr` seems to be interesting. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get rid of the nested loops, but there will still be a lot of code to write. The cleanest way, in my opinion, is to write a custom function that defines how the logic is applied:

```
library(tidyverse)

check_col_validity <- function(col, name) {
  r_error <- rep(NA, length(col))

  # is required?
  if (required_list[name] == 1) {
    msg <- paste(toupper(name), "is required")
    r_error <- ifelse(is.na(col), msg, NA)
  }

  # is continuous?
  if (col_type_list[name] == "continuous") {
    msg <- paste(toupper(name), "must be positive")
    new_error <- ifelse(col < 0 | is.na(col), msg, NA)
    error <- ifelse(is.na(r_error), new_error, paste(r_error, new_error, sep = " & "))
  }

  # is in valid range?
  if (col_type_list[name] == "factor") {
    valid_range <- valid_values[[name]]
    msg <- paste(toupper(name), "must be one of", paste(valid_range, collapse = ", "))
    new_error <- ifelse(col %in% valid_range, NA, msg)
    error <- ifelse(is.na(r_error), new_error, r_error)
  }

  return(error)
}
```

This is a lot like the logic you had. The difference is in how it is applied to the data:

```
dt$error <- dt[, 1:5] %>%
  purrr::imap_dfc(check_col_validity) %>%
  t() %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  purrr::map_chr(paste, collapse = " & ") %>%
  stringr::str_remove_all("NA & ") %>%
  stringr::str_remove_all(" & NA")
```

The function is applied to every column using `purrr::imap`. The result is transposed and pasted together, after which the final step is to remove the ugly NA strings. It delivers the expected result, and I hope the code is clearer to the eye.

The main part about this process is how `imap` works. It is an apply-type operation over a list, but it passes the names of the list elements as the second parameter to the function. This means you can write a custom function that is applied to every column of a dataframe, and add a second parameter to the function to which `imap` will pass the column's name. Once you have both the column's data and name available inside the function, the function becomes a lot easier to write.

The custom function returns the error messages that apply to that column. This means you get a data frame with the same dimensions as your original dataset. You can then transpose this data frame and paste the results for each column together to get 1 message per row.

Comment: Can you little bit explain, how your method is working? It works fine., but I am having hard time to understand col and name parameter.

Comment: I've added some more explanation to my answer. I'd also suggest reading the documentation for `imap` or `purrr` in general if you haven't.

Comment: Sure. I can read it. I am still not sure about `col` & `name` (as per your description . this is names of the list elements), but how about col?

Comment: `imap` passes two arguments to the function: firstly, the list elements, here the columns; secondly, the list names, here the column names.